# Vs Code can't install Ipykernel to Python 3.7.6

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am facing a probably simple issue but couldn't figure it out yet.

I installed a clean OS Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon and installed VS Code and started to run my jupyter notebook file but in the new OS python version is 3.10.12 which is incompitable for my code.
So I installed a 3.7.6 python and started to run my jupyter cells but it threw an error that to run jupyter cells ipykernel should be installed and was asking to install and I tried installed it but it gave an SSL certificate error and I installed it on terminal with the command below:

```
pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall
```

It installed without issue but when I try to run the jupyter cell it throws again the same problem that I need to install ipykernel. I shut down everything and restarted and tried again but it didn't work. It still throws an error that I need to install ipykernel although it is installed. I looked at some solutions but they were for conda environments.
I need to use numpy 1.20.3 to install flask 2.1.0 to install feather.
I know it sounds stupidly. But that is another story.

Btw, VS Code version is 1.81.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have two pip and python interpreters installed. 
Try running `pip -V` and check if it is the same as running `python3.7 -m pip -V` (if that is your python 3.7 interpreter).
Each installation has its own libraries as they are installed in a separate folder.

PS: Python 3.7 reached its EOL two months ago, it is time to upgrade.

Comment: You are right. It is different pip. pip -V command says: pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
and python3.7 -m pip -V gives : pip 23.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
So how can I install packages for python 3.7.6 with pip on terminal?

Comment: With `python3.7 -m pip install <package>`. Please check python VENVS and/or poetry for individual environments for each project, installing all the libraries in the global python installation can break some things if project A and B have a version conflict.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the package, you can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to change the python interpreter.

Then choose the jupyter kernel at the top right corner of the ipynb file.